# Why do I get NaN when I call this factorial function?

Tags: javascript, nan

This is a function to find the factorial. The issue appeared when I added the typeof line. Here is the code:

```
function factorial(num) {
    if ((typeof num) == "number") {
        if (num < 0) {
            error.innerHTML = "Choose a positive number or 0!";
        }
        else if (num == 1 || num == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return num * factorial(num - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever it's called, I do not get a number as an answer and instead get "NaN".

I am trying to calculate permutation with this code:

```
 Math.floor(factorial(n)/factorial(n-r));
```

It does work with normal factorial, but not with that equation.

Comment: I am getting the correct answer. Please check here : https://jsfiddle.net/tc9cqeu4/

Comment: It does work with the equation as well. https://jsfiddle.net/tc9cqeu4/2/. What is the value of n and r variables you are passing ? Could you please add missing code ?

Comment: If you pass a negative value, the function does not return a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably passing a string into your factorial function. This can happen if `n` is set via user input.

`factorial("9") / factorial("4")` returns `NaN`.

To convert a string to a number, use `+`:

```
var n = +myInput.value;
var r = +myOtherInput.value;
console.log( Math.floor(factorial(n) / factorial(n-r)) );
```

Comment: Yes, n was the value of <textarea>. So I shouldn't run into problems if I make it numbers?